# Issues with classes in python

Tags: python, attributes

I'm new to using classes, and am stumped why this error is occurring. Thanks for any help. Directions for assignment:  Accessor methods getStartTime and getEndTime that return their respective values.
Mutator method named start that will reset the startTime to the current time.

```
from time import time
class Stopwatch: 
def __init__(self, startTime, endTime):
    self.startTime =time()
    self.endTime=time()

def getStartTime(self):
    return float(self.startTime)


def getEndTime(self):
    return float(self.endTime)

def start(self):
    self.endTime=time
    return float(self.startTime)


def stop(self):
    self.endTime=time
    return float(self.startTime)

>>> a=Stopwatch
>>> a.getStartTime(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    a.getStartTime(a)
  File "/Users/baileyrockwell/Documents/hw9.py", line 55, in    getStartTime
    return float(self.startTime)
AttributeError: type object 'Stopwatch' has no attribute 'startTime'
```

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here; the first of which is that you have some missing parentheses to handle: when defining `start` and `stop`, it should be `self.endTime=time()`; when instantiating a `Stopwatch` object, it should be `a=Stopwatch(startTime, endTime)`.

Comment: Also, I would define the `__init__` method with only `self` as a parameter and then play with the `start` and `stop` functions to define the start and end times.

Comment: thank you, I figured it out.